# How to use fgets and sscanf to store data into structure, from text file

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

What i want to do is to take a text file and store the 4 lines into my structure, using a loop with fgets and sscanf to retrieve the data.

The structure is this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define SIZE 16
 #define N 4

struct Prova
{
    char nome[SIZE];
    int num;
};
```

Now my function looks like this:

```
void get_str(struct Prova * ptr){

FILE *f;
int i = 0;

 if(!(f = fopen(PATH,"r+")))
  {
    perror("Errore in apertura");
    exit(0);
  }

void * buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Prova ));

  while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct Prova), f))
   {
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", (ptr+i)->nome, &(ptr+i)->num) > 0)
      {i++;}
   }

   free(buffer);
   fclose(f);
  }
```

UPDATED: Now the function works, thanks everybody.

Main function is this:

```
  int main()
  {
    struct Prova * ptr = malloc(N*sizeof(struct Prova));

    get_str(ptr);

    for(int i = 0; i< N; i++)
    {
      printf("\n%s %d", (ptr+i)->nome, (ptr+i)->num);
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

The text file i'm trying to read is this:

```
Pippo 4
Paperino 1
Topolino 3
Zio_paperone 2
```

Comment: Are you sure that the characters between `Paperino` and `1` and between `Topolino` and `3` are _actually_ spaces (code 0x20) and not non breaking spaces (code 0xa0)? In most text editors they look the same and you can't tell the difference

Comment: `fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct Prova), f)` is not really correct, since you really want `[at most SIZE - 1 characters][space][1 digit][maybe a newline]`, not `[at most SIZE - 1 characters][space][sizeof(int) digits]`, and that's not even considering the possibility of padding, etc. It's probably "close enough" in practice but seems off semantically.

Comment: You also need to check the return value of  `sscanf`. You don't, and that's why the last `0` is printed

Comment: @underscore_d  "[at most SIZE - 1 characters][space][1 digit]" also needs room for a `'\n'` and `'\0'`.  OTOH just use a buffer 2x expected size needs.  A slightly too big a buffer is not a problem.

Comment: @chux Good point: edited. Yeah, in this case, it would make as much sense just to overallocate slightly - if not more, as that reduces the risk of accidentally too-long lines causing anything to explode. However, the code instead implies it's trying to be very specific about the size, but uses the wrong basis; that's my gripe.

Comment: By changing the post significantly after answers arrived, your post makes little sense.  Roll back to a version that make sense with the good answer supplied.  You can post your own answer below if desired.  FWIW, your answer (in this post) has various short-comings in it even if it fulfills the  post's original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others in comments check the return value of `sscanf()`. Also I'm not sure what argument you are passing to `get_str()`.

Also In `void * buffer = malloc(N*sizeof(struct Prova ));` you no need to allocate memory for `N structure` because using `fgets()` you are overwriting data every time. It should be `void * buffer = malloc(2*sizeof(struct Prova ));`

For particular case you mention, it might be the solution

```
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct Prova), f)) {
       int ret = sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", (ptr+i)->nome, &(ptr+i)->num);
       printf("ret = %d\n",ret);
       printf("\n%s %d", (ptr+i)->nome, (ptr+i)->num);
       i++;
}
```

Here is the complete code

```
#define N 4
struct Prova {
        char nome[SIZE];
        int num;
};
void get_str(struct Prova * ptr) {
        FILE *f;
        if(!(f = fopen("data","r+"))) {
                perror("Error");
                exit(0);
        }
        void * buffer = malloc(2*sizeof(struct Prova ));/* Allocate 2* size, by considering Newline char & possible padding */ 
        int i =0;
        while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct Prova), f)) {
                int ret = sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", (ptr+i)->nome, &(ptr+i)->num);
                printf("ret = %d\n",ret);
                i++;
        }
        free(buffer);
        fclose(f);
}
int main() {
        struct Prova *v = malloc(N*sizeof(struct Prova));/* here you need to allocate 
                                for N structure, amke sure file have N lines of same format */
        get_str(v);
        for(int i =0;i<N;i++) {
                printf("\n%s %d\n",(v+i)->nome,(v+i)->num);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945513/how-to-use-fgets-and-sscanf-to-store-data-into-structure-from-text-file#comment86907591_49945513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945513/how-to-use-fgets-and-sscanf-to-store-data-into-structure-from-text-file#comment86907633_49945513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945513/how-to-use-fgets-and-sscanf-to-store-data-into-structure-from-text-file#comment86907699_49945513), the size allocated for `buffer` borders on being insufficient.  Suggest something larger, perhaps 2x `sizeof(struct Prova )`?

Comment: i tried to increase the buffer, but the problem still occurs, i still have that 0 printed :\

Comment: St3veR0nix Did you apply the fix suggested by [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945513/how-to-use-fgets-and-sscanf-to-store-data-into-structure-from-text-file/49945830?noredirect=1#comment86907630_49945513) ?

Comment: Yes, i put an if statement to check the return value of sscanf

Comment: @St3veR0nix example input you mentioned that contains `4` lines but you define `#define N 5` make it `N` as `4`

Comment: Better find the `line count` in the file first and allocate memory for that many lines only.